# This could be another Riley's Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

I'm the beginning, and I'll be the end.
When I'm gone, so will you, my friend.
I am the power, the power of life.
Without me, nothing can survive.
Now you know the rules of my game
I want you to guess my name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> The sun?

I'm the beginning, and I'll be the end.

> the sun made life on earth possible. Scientists have predicted that the suns lifespan will end in about 10 billion years, and all life on earth (if still alive then) will then go extict.

When I'm gone, so will you, my friend.

> When the sun dies, the earth will be too cold for you to live (or too hot at first, while the sun grows enormously just before it dies)

I am the power, the power of life.

> The heat coming from the sun is energy (power) that allows life on earth to exist.

Without me, nothing can survive.

> no sun -> no heat -> no life. <sup>I'm starting to repeat myself..</sup>

I want you to guess my name.

> although it's custom for such riddles to ask 'what's my name?' even for objects, The sun has had many names in many religions; Helios, Ra, Sol, ...

Comment: good job, kudos to you!

Comment: yay ^.^ nice riddle

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is

> Time?
>
>  When we start or end something, we usually talk about time.
>  When your time is gone it means you're gone too.
>  Obviously, the time is a power of life.
>  And finally it is impossible to imagine a life without the time therefore nothing can survive without it.

Comment: nice shot, but you missed... I will provide an hint if you want

Comment: don't break the intrigue) i'll try again

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how this is a Riley riddle, but

> Are you water?

I'm the beginning, and I'll be the end.

> Water has been around forever, and it'll be here until the heat death of the universe.

I am the power, the power of life.

> Water = Carbon-based life. (Of course, there could be non-carbon based life forms that we don't know of, but all life we know of is formed because of water).

Without me, nothing can survive.

> Without water, everything would die.

Comment: sorry, this is not the answer. I always thought a Riley Riddle rhymes... if that's not the case I apologize for the misleading title (I come from Germany)

Comment: @D3f4u1t, It's okay. At least here, a Riley riddle is one that describes the word you are talking about with its prefix, infix, suffix, etc. I'm not sure if it stems from our puzzler Riley or not. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Riley did indeed come up with the first of those riddles

Comment: Regarding your explanation to the first line of the riddle, (ROT13) Jngre unfa'g npghnyyl orra nebhaq sberire. Nf n znggre bs snpg, vg vf oryvrirq vg pnzr sebz penfurq zrgrbevgrf fvapr gurl pna pbagnva vpr, naq nf vg ragref gur Rnegu'f ngzbfcurer, gurl urng hc (naq fvapr vg vf erplpyrq sebz gur jubyr jngre plpyr naq nyy, vs gur oryvrs vf gehr, jngre vf yvgrenyyl fcnpr yvdhvq!); ohg ng gur raq bs gur qnl, guvf vf whfg n gurbel (yvxr rirelguvat, ernyyl). Gnyxvat nobhg fpvragvsvp oryvrsf, vg vf nyfb oryvrirq gung Rnegu jnf svefgyl sbezrq qel.